# what jquery plugins does stackoverflow use when you highlight over tags in a question

Tags: discussion, jquery

it now seems to allow you to add to interested or add to ignore when you highlight over that tag.  Does anyone know what plugin is used to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear, this only happens when browsing `/questions/tagged/` -- I think it's just vanilla jQuery.

Comment: Yep, plain ol' Jquery - it's awesome!

Comment: thanks.  whats the reasoning for hvaing it just on tagged pages.  why not have it on every page as it allows you to do it not only to the tag in the url?

Comment: @oo: oh, please don't...